# Is there a limit to processes I can run in the background?

Tags: background-process, jobs, processes

Is there a limit to how many jobs you can have running in the background when using command prompt? I've heard varying answers to this question, but is there a concrete number that is set as the limit?

Answer (score 2):

This is defined in each shell's source code for `jobs` as the size of the job table and presumably it should keep a general resemblance with the resource limit for maximum number of processes of a user.

In `bash` it's 8192, from `jobs.c` of `bash` source code:

```
#if !MAX_CHILD_MAX
#  define MAX_CHILD_MAX 8192
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As foreground/background is entirely a shell thing (it might affect which filehandles are passed to a process, but that can be affected in other ways), such a limit would have to come from your shell. I've never heard of a shell setting a limit, and as far as I can tell, it would require more code for no real gain, so I doubt any shell does, but there are lots of shells I haven't tried and (probably) more I haven't even heard of.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Linux and use the bash shell pretty much 99% of the time. I know foreground processes are limited to one at a time since the process consumes the command line, but as far as you know, bash has no limit on background processes?

Comment: Bash uses a [linked list of a structure](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.h) so memory might be a limiting factor, if cpu isn't

Comment: Each process consumes a number of file descriptors, which are also finite resources.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I hadn't thought of that. that might actually set a limit, but I'm guessing it will be pretty high.